# In ASP.NET Core, how to know the user meets the minimum age?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization, claims-based-identity, asp.net-core-identity

I am following this tutorial on authorization in asp.net core: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-3.0

The example creates a MinimumAgeRequirement and sets its age to 21.
The problem is I can't find where in the code it sets the user's age to 21. So it seems like the requirement will never be met?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For adding claims to user:

```
await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(user, new Claim(ClaimTypes.DateOfBirth, myDateOfBirth));
```

You can find the complete project with AgeRequirement, Handler, Claim and Authorize on HomeController.

https://github.com/zubairrana/CustomClaimValidation/

Answer (score 0):

The minimum requirement is reinforced by the auth claim where the loggedin user context is used to check date of birth and compare with the minimum age requirement. Here is the code snippet.

```
var dateOfBirth = Convert.ToDateTime(
            context.User.FindFirst(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.DateOfBirth && 
                                        c.Issuer == "http://contoso.com").Value);
```